Where to override pager settings for specific displays?
I have a view on Drupal 10 that has several "block" displays, and one "attachment" display.
If I change one of the block pager settings, those settings are also applied to other block displays of my view. On the other hand, if I change the pager settings on the attachment display, they are onnly applied on that display and not on the block displays.
With Drupal 7, I was able to have different pager settings on multiple block displays of a view. Do I face a bug of the D10 views module, or is it supposed to behave this way on D10?
I just need to have a block display with pager settings like "show 2, pass 1", and another block display (on the same view) with pager settings like "show 1, pass 0".

When you change the settings did you select All displays (except overridden) or This block (override)?

@monalisa When I edit pager settings, it doesn't show the select with "All displays" or "This block". This select is here on Drupal 7 when I edit the pager settings, or on Drupal 10 when I edit other settings of the display. But not on Drupal 10 when I edit the pager settings.

You won't see the dropdown to override in the pager settings. You have to set it in the pager type. Once you've done that any pager settings should only reflect for that block/attachment


Oh you are right ... D7 was showing the dropdown on both pager settings screens, but D10 only shows it on the page type screen, like you say. Thank you very much :)
